# R nested loop ggplot, need storage object with multiple dimensions

Tags: arrays, r, list, loops, ggplot2

I would like to write a nested loop to:

- generate multiple ggplots
- run regressions

I use the following code:

```
#create alternative data set
mtcars1 <- filter(mtcars, disp >= 100)

#create data, x variable, and y variable lists
data_list <- c('mtcars', 'mtcars_1')
x_list <- c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')
y_list <- c('hp', 'drat', 'wt')

#create empty lists for plots and regressions generated by loop
plots <- list()
regressions <- list()

#loop
for (i in length(data_list)){
  for (j in 1:length(x_list)) {
    for (k in 1:length(y_list)) {
      plots[[i, j, k]] <- ggplot(data_list[i], aes_string(x = x_list[j], y = y_list[k])) + 
        geom_point(size = 2) + 
        xlab(x_list[j]) + 
        ylab(y_list[k])

      regressions[[i, j, k]] <- lm(y_list[k] ~ x_list[j], data = data_list[i])

    }
  }
}
```

Two issues:

1. Is there an "aes_string" equivalent for the ggplot data input?
2. I need some type of object that exists in multiple dimensions and can hold many types of objects. Lists can hold any type of object but are one-dimensional. Arrays can have many dimensions, but can only hold single values.

Perhaps I can generate multiple lists?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can have lists inside matrices if you set them up right.

```
plots <- array(list(), dim = c(2, 2, 2)) # must be initialized with list type
ggp <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, gear)) + geom_point()
plots[[1, 1, 1]] <- ggp # double brackets are important
plots[[1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like dash2's answer as an alternative you can add dimensionality to lists by nesting then. Below is a 2 dimensional lists i.e list of 2 lists.

```
library(ggplot2)

plot1<-ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=cyl))+geom_point()
lm1<-lm(mpg~as.factor(cyl),data=mtcars)
plot2<-ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=disp))+geom_point()
lm2<-lm(mpg~as.factor(disp),data=mtcars)

myList<-list("plots"=list("plot1"=plot1,"plot2"=plot2),"models"=list("lm1"=lm1,"lm2"=lm2))
```

By nesting lists inside lists you can have as many dimensions a you want.